# Why does $\langle a_-\alpha|\alpha\rangle = \alpha $ for harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, harmonic-oscillator, coherent-states

Given $|\alpha\rangle$ a coherent state, why does $\langle a_-\alpha|\alpha\rangle  = \alpha$? Doesn't the ladder operator lower the $\alpha$ so that it becomes $\sqrt{\alpha}\,\delta_{\alpha, \alpha_{-1}}$?

Maybe it's because that $\alpha$ can be imaginary? In that case how would you prove the above relation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you don't say so in your question, it's clear from the context that $|\alpha\rangle$ is here being used to denote a so-called [**coherent state**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states#Quantum_mechanical_definition) defined by the condition that it is an eigenvector of the lowering operator;
\begin{align}
  a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle.
\end{align}
It follows that
\begin{align}
  \langle \alpha|a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha \langle \alpha|\alpha\rangle = \alpha
\end{align}
where in the last step we have assumed that the coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ is normalized to one;
\begin{align}
  \langle \alpha|\alpha\rangle = 1.
\end{align}